# jQuery Ajax success function returns null on specific server

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is driving me crazy! My code works on my computer, works on an online server, but returns null on another server!!

Any idea??

Here is the jQuery Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mailchimp.php',
            data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($('#email').val()) + '&phone=' + escape($('#phone').val()) + '&uname=' + encodeURIComponent($('#uname').val()) ,
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#form').html(msg);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I tested mailchimp.php by direct url typing; it works fine and echoing the results as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Debug this on the php side, for example, have it write the passed in data to a local file or a log. I don't think jQuery is going to have anything to do with this. Although, you should be declaring the request as either POST or GET to ensure it is sent the way the server expects it.

Comment: inspect the request from browser, observe what data and content type has been requested and whats the response returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving absolute path to the url and try. I might be wrong, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting cross domain? Then you should be using JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

Comment: I just noticed that the post doesn't take place when I enter Arabic text! It works when I enter English. I'm not posting cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what's the exact problem but it seems that the ajax post is not being executed due to the existence of the percentage symbol that is generated by the encodeURIComponent function.

Here is what I did in my ajax function. I replaced all the % symbols with the hyphen symbol.

```
uname = uname.replace(/\%/g, '-');
```

And in my PHP code, I put all the % symbols back instead of the hyphens.

```
urldecode(str_replace('-', '%', $_GET['uname']))
```

Maybe that's not the best solution, but it finally works :)